# mongodb query: how to get unique entries

Tags: mongodb

I have, let's say 100 rows. In each collection, there is an 'id' field.
Let's say of the 100 rows, 20 rows have an 'id' of 10, 30 rows have an 'id' of 11 and 50 rows have an 'id' of 12.
My query should return:
10 - 20 (count)
11 - 30 (count)
12 - 50 (count).

How do I write this query?

Answer (score 2):

If your collection is called "foo", the following will work.

```
> db.foo.group({
    key: {id: true},
    initial: {count: 0},
    reduce: function(doc, aggregator) {
    aggregator.count += 1;
  }
})
```

It will produce results as follows:

```
[
{
    "id" : 10,
    "count" : 20
},
{
    "id" : 11,
    "count" : 30
},
{
    "id" : 12,
    "count" : 50
}
]
```

There is further detail on group(), and some examples, here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation

The new Aggregation Framework is substantially more sophisticated. You can find out about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: Hi Ian Daniel, This is works for me thank you very much. I have one more thing to do in it, that is i need two more fields to get in the same collection. For example, i have a collection called userStoredInfo in which i have "userId, files, fielssize, infos" as a fields.. Now i want do is, get count of the infos, total no:of files, total file size based on userId.. Any suggestion or help will appreciated... Thanks...