# mongodb query: how to get unique entries, sum of a column, count etc.,

Tags: jsp, mongodb

With respected to this link [mongodb query: how to get unique entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028320/mongodb-query-how-to-get-unique-entries)

I tried this command,

```
db.userInfo.group({key: {userID: true}, initial: {filescount: 0}, reduce: function(doc, aggregator) { aggregator.filescount += 1;}});
```

this will return as like below,

```
[
    {
            "userID" : "50d002940cf2298e9721642d",
            "filescount" : 2
    },
    {
            "userID" : "50b9d10e0cf2362982338e38",
            "filescount" : 12
    }
]
```

this is ok for getting only the count of values, I need to something like below

```
[
    {
            "userID" : "50d002940cf2298e9721642d",
            "filescount" : 2,
            "filesTotalSize" : 1000,
            "physicalFilescount" : 1
    },
    {
            "userPID" : "50b9d10e0cf2362982338e38",
            "filescount" : 12,
            "filesTotalSize" : 10000,
            "physicalFilescount" : 10
    }
]
```

In which filesTotalsize is a total of all filesSize field, physicalFilescount is no of physical files stored in the users colelction.

Any help will appreciated and helpful to me.
Thanks,
Annamalai.Lk

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the aggregation framework [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/)? Could please you edit your question to include these details (and make this a full question rather than quoting a comment)?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following js for extract the details,

```
print("Number of Users info Collection is : "+db.user.find({},{_id:1}).count());
print("userID,EmailId,Age,Sex,fileCount,TotalPhysicalFiles,TotalFileSize");

//user is a collection based on that i get values from the userFiles collection
//(i.e) each user have some files in userFiles collection..
//So that i really want to get each users
//files count, actual files count, sizeused field values

db.user.find().forEach( function(user) {
var fileCount = 0;
var totalPhysicalFiles = 0;
if(user != undefined)
{       
    db.userFiles.find().forEach( function(userFiles) { 
        if(userFiles.userID == user._id)
        {
            fileCount++;
            if(userFiles.fileURL != undefined)
                totalPhysicalFiles++;
        }           
    });
    var userRoleId = user.appRole.$id;
    var userType = "";
    if(userRoleId == "01")
        userType = "ADMIN";
    else
        userType = "USER";
    print(user._id+","+user.userId+","+user.age+","+user.sex+","+fileCount+","+totalPhysicalFiles+","+user.sizeUsed);
}});
```

finally execute this js from the command prompt using the following command as like,

./mongo localhost:27017/testDB getUserCount.js > test.csv

it will generate a csv file in that path.